# Converting nested JSON array

Tags: php, javascript, json

I have a PHP function that builds a JSON array via

```
$jsonArray= array();
for ($i=0; $i<$dirCount; $i++){
  $query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM tour WHERE FileName= '../%s/%s'", $imageDirectory, $dirArrays[$i]);
  $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
    $jsonArray[]= array('filename'=>$dirArrays[$i], 'location'=>$row[4], 'latitude'=>$row[2], 'longitude'=>$row[3], 'heading'=> $row[5]);
  } 
}
```

and returns it upon execution via an ajax query.

However, it is shown in Firebug as

```
[
  0 : Object{ 'filename' : , 'location': , 'latitude': , 'longitude: },
  1 : Object{ 'filename' : , 'location': , 'latitude': , 'longitude: }, 
]
```

and so on

How can I convert this so that the index locations are the `location` value instead?  What I have in mind is

```
'start' : Object{ 'filename' : , 'location': , 'latitude': , 'longitude: },
'testLab' : { 'filename' : , 'location': , 'latitude': , 'longitude: }
```

The reason behind this is I have another function that creates an object with the data fields upon a match to the location field.

```
function buildData(input){
  for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    if (data[i].location == input)
      //create and return object using data[i] fields
  } 
}
```

I'd like get rid of the loop and rely on the conditional like

```
function buildData(input){
  if (data[input]){
    //same object creation and return
  }
}
```

How would this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of just pushing each element of the array (`$jsonArray[] = ...`), just assign to the relevant key (`$jsonArray[$somekey] = ...`).